# Is it true that the scriptural texts denying the attributes of Brahman are of greater authority than those affirming attributes?

Tags: vishnu, krishna, advaita, brahman, vishishtadvaita

[image]

I was reading Sampathkumaran's translation of Gita Bhashya by Sri Ramanuja. I found this written in the commentary of 2.13. I wonder if this is true.

Comment: I can either wear clothes or not wear them, right ? Similarly, Bhagavan can be both with and without form.. what is so hard to understand about this ?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you are talking about Gita 2.13? Gita 2.13 does not deal with attributes at all.

> Just as the self associated with a body passes through childhood,
> youth and old age, so one at (death) It passes into another body. A
> wise man is not deluded by that.

**Gita 2.13**

I am surprised that Sri Ramanuja's Gita bhasya says that the scriptural verses denying attributes are more authoritative than affirming attributes. It is Sankaracharya's position.

> 'Hence in sentences of this kind, the formless Brahman alone, just as
> It is spoken of by the texts themselves, has to be accepted. But the
> other texts, speaking of Brahman with form, have injunctions about
> meditations as their main objectives. So long as they do not lead to
> some contradiction, their apparent meanings should be accepted. But
> when they involve a contradiction, the principle to be followed for
> deciding one or the other is that, **those that have formless Brahman as
> their main purport are more authoritative than the others which have
> not that as their main purport.** It is according to this that one is
> driven to the conclusion that Brahman is formless and not its
> opposite, though texts having both the purports are in evidence.'

**Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Sri Sankaracharya III.II.14**

Comment: At the level of words these are just games.  Totapuri made Ramakrishna apprehend Nirguna Brahman only after the latter could temporarily give up his beloved Kali